# Do I always have to peel garlic?

Tags: spices

Is it safe to prepare ginger garlic paste without peeling garlic skin ?? I always peel garlic which is a labourious and time taking process. I would like to know whether if it is ok to make paste without peeling skin of the garlic.

Comment: Peeling garlic shouldn't be a difficult process.  See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/895/67 .  If you're peeling lots of garlic, see the second answer.  I think there's another answer somewhere (as I remember doing some experiments on see how much crowding the bowls affected the peeling last year)

Comment: Found it : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/45470/67

Comment: Buy "garlic paste" have you considered doing roasted garlic? http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/roasted-garlic-102291

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that this would be unsafe, as you do see unpeeled garlic used in some applications, but it wouldn't be particularly pleasant and you probably wouldn't end up with a great paste. Garlic skins can be pretty tough and woody depending on the particular bulb; you'd probably end up with hard, fibrous bits in your paste.

If you're willing to accept this negative impact to the final texture, then I suppose you could try it. But as @Joe points out, you're better off working on an improved method of [peeling your garlic](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/895/how-do-you-peel-garlic-easily), which will serve you well no matter what you're cooking.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a garlic press such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HEZ888K) one, you don't have to peel the garlic (though you'll have less waste if you do).