# Garlic skin edible?

Tags: food-safety, garlic

I know the peel on the cloves of garlic are edible, but what abput the papery skin on the outside covering all of it? I feel dumb for asking this but is there a difference?
The post/question in the following link got answers about the peel, and not skin/paper on the outside. Again, sorry if this is redundant.

[Is garlic peel safe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/75686/is-garlic-peel-safe-to-eat)

Comment: Welcome to the site @Kyle. This is really the same question, so it is a duplicate. The outer layers are pretty much the same material, you can eat it but you don't want to.

Comment: I agree with closing as a duplicate, since the accepted answer there already says "There's not really any difference between the outer and inner layers of the peel". I hope you don't take this as a negative evaluation of your question - it is actually impressive that, as a new user, you took the time to find and link a related question, many people don't bother. Closing a question as a duplicate is, for our site, a matter of housekeeping and making sure information is easy to find, not fragmented between questions. It is not a punishment for the asker and has no bad consequences for you.

Comment: ok. It was just confusing in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I would not eat them, but you *can* save them to help season stock. Wrap them in a bundle of cheesecloth and let them simmer along with all your other vegetable trimmings to get a light garlic addition to your flavor.